# SSIS process greyed out

Tags: ssis

Unfortunately my SSIS process is greyed out like shown below (the tasks are not disabled!). The executed process stops immediately with "Validation is completed". Is there any way to reactivate the process? All connections/containers/tasks are working fine if executed manually.

[image]

Greyed out process:

[image: Greyed out process]

All tasks are enabled:
[image: Enabled task]

Comment: This looks very much like it *is* disabled; why do you say it isn't?

Comment: They mean it definitely isn't, but it looks like it is- that's the problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why all the tasks were greyed out?  I'm seeing similar behavior after merging a couple of branches in Hg.  A pre-execute breakpoint on the first task is never being hit after the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a new package and copy-pasted all tasks and connections from the old package into the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but just in case someone else is encountering the same problem.

In my case the issue was that the package itself was disabled.
I use Expressions based on parameters on various containers in the package to set the value of the Disabled properties. One of the Expression was assigned to the Disabled property of the package instead of one of the containers, and the condition was satisfied for the Disabled property to be set to true.
When I removed the Expression for the package's Disabled property, it retained the latest value, so it was set to True; I just had to set it back to False, and it started working again.

Best regards,

Alain.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The one marked as the answer doesn't actually solve the issue.